# CSS Spec: block-level box, block container box and block box

Tags: css

I am reading [CSS Spec 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html) and find the concepts hard to distinguish:

> Except for table boxes, which are described in a later chapter, and replaced elements, a block-level box is also a block container box. A block container box either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only inline-level boxes. Not all block container boxes are block-level boxes: non-replaced inline blocks and non-replaced table cells are block containers but not block-level boxes. Block-level boxes that are also block containers are called block boxes.

May I interpret the description above as follow?:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.

Here are some additional details:

- The reason a table box is not a block container is because it establishes a table layout, not a block layout. Content goes into the cell elements rather than the table element, which is why it is the *cell* boxes that are block containers rather than the table box itself.
- A replaced element doesn't contain any other content and therefore cannot be a block container.
- The only difference between a block box and an inline-block is that the former is block-level while the latter is inline-level. Hence the display values `display: block` and `display: inline-block` respectively. As both are block containers, there is no difference in how their contents are formatted.

Note that replaced elements and table boxes can be either inline-level or block-level. Inline tables and inline replaced elements are simply excluded from the section you quote because that section only pertains to block-level boxes; you'll find references to them elsewhere in section 9, or in sections [10](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html) and [17](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html) respectively.

Also, even though a block container box can only either contain block-level boxes or inline-level boxes, you can still mix both in the same block container box; internally it simply segregates the block-level and inline-level boxes via [anonymous block boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level).

Comment: It feels very complicated to comprehend the visual formatting modal. Especially sub topics 9.2 and 9.4.  I wish the standard could have done a better job explaining these topics, just like it did for rest of the topics.

Comment: @Binary_10: The standard wasn't (always) intended to be a resource for web developers. It was written the way it was so everything was spelled out as clearly as possible for browser developers. That said, I think the CSSWG is working to make modern specs easier to understand.

Comment: Then what is the best resource for developers to gain deeper knowledge and to lay a solid foundation (CSS) ?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that HTML is a tree so each node can act as both a parent (of children) and child (of a parent)

Bearing this in mind, things start to make sense, **Block-level box** refers to box act as **chlid**

> Block-level boxes are boxes that participate in a block formatting
> context.

On the other hand, **block container box** refer to a **parent** who can contain others

> A block container box either contains only block-level boxes or
> establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only
> inline-level boxes

Just like a node can **either** be a child and a parent, an HTML node can either act as a parent(block container box) or child (block-level box) or **BOTH**

For example, if children in a node are not allowed (replaced element), it can never be a parent, it can only be a child (Block-level boxes) at most, not a parent (block container box)

And there is no reason to prevent a non-block parent contain a block parent. An `inline-block` itself is not a block, but it can contain **block-level box**

The point is a spec is easier to understand from a parent-child view