# If Inline box is relative positioning, then what is its block-level box affected by?

Tags: html, css

source spec: [Anonymous block boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level).

I'm confused about this sentence.

> When such an inline box is affected by relative positioning, any resulting translation also affects the block-level box contained in the inline box.

I don't know whether the "relative positioning" is the general meaning, I mean it can be `absolute` or `fixed`, and other properties of `display`, e.g, `inline-block`.

Let's see examples.

I know `DIV` broke the `line box`, but `position: relative` seems useless, I can remove it directly.

```css
.father {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span class="father">
  <div>Hi Wick</div>
</span>
```

But, If I modified `relative` to `absolute`, I knew the `line box` wasn't "broke", so `border` worked normally. If I added the `inline-block` property of `display`, the result is the same.

```css
.father {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span class="father">
  <div>Hi Wick</div>
</span>
```

Also, what does `any resulting translation` mean? I know some behaviors may change `containing block`, so they will be affected by their descendants. I'm not sure whether it is about the `containing block`.

Therefore, I need some examples!

Comment: Your example HTML does not really follow in the context/concept of the anonymous block - which is the block around the text above the `p` block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying Anonymous Block Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981136/identifying-anonymous-block-boxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<span>` element is inline, which means it has no "box" around it to apply a border to. It's treated the same as a line of text with no container. Imagine it as a horizontal line where the center of each letter inside it is placed on that line. Applying `position: absolute;` to a `<span>` causes it to be treated the same as if it was `display: block;`, which is why the `border` property works on it then.

In your first example, the inner `div` is a block level element inside an inline element. If you applied a border to the `div`, you'd see it stretches across the width of the container to fill the space horizontally. Since the parent span is inline, the border doesn't show like you want it to, but the height of the child `div` at least gives some level of "size" to the span, if only vertically.

Also, "any resulting translations" just refers to CSS properties that move the element on the screen, such as `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`, or `transform: translate();`.

Comment: Ohhh, I need the last sentence that resolves my confusion. I misunderstand `translations`!